# How can I tell if CEDET is using GNU Global?

Tags: cedet, emacs24

I have CEDET working for the most part on emacs 24.2 with the latest from bzr
repository.

When I am searching for symbols or definitions, I see that the cedet mini-buffer 
shows parses through a lot of files, some that are not there as header-files, the files
do not have any reference to the symbols I am searching. 
I will leave CEDET to its job, let it search for symbols as it sees fit.

Is there any debug mechanism or verbose mode that I can turn on to see 
1) What are all the files it is searching.
2) If it has found the GTAGS file at the base of my project. I understand that CEDET only
consults the GTAGS file to know about symbols.

I ask because there are some symbols that CEDET is unable to find the definition
for, but I'm able to find it from the gtags command line.

Thanks to Alex and Eric for their Numerous posts through-out the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a multi-step process.

First, make sure you've setup Global in the ways you want, such as via ede's locate feature, and through Symref.

Next, while visiting a file in a project you care about, use:

```
M-x cedet-gnu-global-show-root RET
```

to see if it can find a Global index file in that project.

Next, to see if symref found it, you need to eval this:

```
M-: (semantic-symref-detect-symref-tool)
```

and it will give you a symbol representing the tool it has chosen to use.  It will say `'grep` if it failed to use Global.

If you were in the middle of configuring things, you might need to reset things for you buffer.  An easy way is to kill the buffer, and find it again, or:

```
M-x (setq semantic-symref-tool 'detect) RET
```

to force a detection again.

Comment: I got everything passing these requirements, but the buffer that comes up is empty, extreme example: used it to check for kmalloc in kernel code, empty buffer for results.