# CEDET cannot use GNU Global for Symref

Tags: emacs, cedet

I already enable using GNU Global databases:

```
(setq cedet-global-command "global")
(when (cedet-gnu-global-version-check t)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t))
```

`cedet-gnu-global-version-check` shows correct version and `cedet-gnu-global-show-root` jumps to correct project root. However, according to Eric's answer here: [How can I tell if CEDET is using GNU Global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791246/how-can-i-tell-if-cedet-is-using-gnu-global), evaluating `(semantic-symref-detect-symref-tool)` always gives me `grep`, even though CEDET recognized GNU Global version.

How can I really enable CEDET to use GNU Global?

Edit: I have to force CEDET to use GNU Global:

```
(setq-default semantic-symref-tool "global")
```

Not sure if this is a correct way to setup, but currently this is my workaround to make CEDET use GNU Global. Or maybe `(semantic-symref-detect-symref-tool)` is buggy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your edit, setting `semantic-symref-tool` to "global" is a fine way to start using it.

The detect mechanism (the default) will try to use Global iff there is a `GPATH` file at the root of your project.  The root of your project is identified via EDE, or perhaps the current directory.   Thus if you have some project in `~/myproj`, but `GPATH` is in `~/myproj/src`, then it will get missed.

Comment: How do I hard code/set the project? Spent so much time wasted with EDE and couldn't get it to work correctly.